# How do you extract all CSS files into one file resolving same named css selectors using webpack?

Tags: css, webpack

So I've been developing all modules for my project in each separate environment. I have multiple css files for each modules.
And what I've read from stackoverflow is to have one css file in production. So I have used webpack  '**MiniCssExtractPlugin**' to extract all css files into one css file and it actually works just fine.

*However there's one caveat.*

What this '**MiniCssExtractPlugin**' does is basically concatenating all css files into one css file. what I thought of it was going to do is if there's a same name of css selectors, it will integrate it into one css selector with merging all properties of that selector that exists in one file but don't in another file.

For example, if I have two css files called `a.css` and `b.css`,

```css
/* a.css */
:root {
  --color-text-1: #e4e4e4;
  --color-text-2: #d8d8d8;
  --font-weight-normal: 400;
  --font-weight-medium: 500;
  --font-weight-semi-bold: 600;
  --font-weight-bold: 700;
}

/* b.css */
:root {
  --font-weight-normal: 400;
  --font-weight-medium: 500;
  --font-weight-semi-bold: 600;
  --font-weight-bold: 700;
  --card-above-font-color: #d8d8d8;
  --card-above-bg-color: #252525;
}
```

What I expected the bundled css file would be

```css
/* bundled.css */
:root {
  --color-text-1: #e4e4e4;
  --color-text-2: #d8d8d8;
  --font-weight-normal: 400;
  --font-weight-medium: 500;
  --font-weight-semi-bold: 600;
  --font-weight-bold: 700;
  --card-above-font-color: #d8d8d8;
  --card-above-bg-color: #252525;
}
```

**But my actual bundled css file is**

```css
/* actual bundled.css */
:root {
  --color-text-1: #e4e4e4;
  --color-text-2: #d8d8d8;
  --font-weight-normal: 400;
  --font-weight-medium: 500;
  --font-weight-semi-bold: 600;
  --font-weight-bold: 700;
}

:root {
  --font-weight-normal: 400;
  --font-weight-medium: 500;
  --font-weight-semi-bold: 600;
  --font-weight-bold: 700;
  --card-above-font-color: #d8d8d8;
  --card-above-bg-color: #252525;
}
```

So my question is, **How do you extract all CSS files into one file resolving same named css selectors using webpack?**

And is this a normally good practice? I found it super helpful to develop in separate css files because I could just focus on styling that module, however now it's sort of difficult to combine it all.

Comment: I don't see the difference between actual & expected version :]

Comment: @felixmosh My bad! I just edited

Answer (score 0):

The `MiniCssExtractPlugin` extracts CSS. Nothing more.

Your use case sound like "postprocessing" the CSS. For example you could try `postcss` and the Webpack `postcss-loader` with a plugin.

`npm install --save-dev postcss-loader postcss`

configure the loader:

```
rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
```

and try maybe this plugin:

https://github.com/georgeadamson/postcss-merge-selectors

Comment: Yeah, this seems somewhat similar, but slightly different than what I want to achieve. This merge selectors that have same rules, but in my css files, I actually have identical selectors, and I want some plugin(if it exists) to merge all the properties while resolving same properties under same selector.